# Why the update query is not working in this function?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

I want to toggle the activation status of a company in my code. So first I take activation_status, toggle it and then fire the update query. But it is showing that con.query1() is not a function.

I have checked all the possible mistakes still not able to find it.

I searched on many websites but it says that it will be spelling mistakes.

```
var val;
app.post("/edit/company", (req, res) => {
  let comid = req.body.comid;
  let sql = "SELECT is_active from tblcompany where cid='" + comid + "'";
  let query = con.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    val = result[0].is_active;

    if (val == "1") val = 0;
    else val = 1;

    console.log("Value of Activation Status: " + val);
  });
  console.log("Value of activation status:" + val);
  console.log("Value of Company" + comid);

  let sql1 =
    "UPDATE tblcompany SET is_active=" + val + " where cid=" + comid + "";
  let query1 = con.query1(sql1, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    // res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
  });
});
```

Comment: Tried `let query1 = con.query(sql1, ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid some check just using SQL

```
  UPDATE tblcompany SET is_active =  case when is_active  = 1 then 0 else 1 end 
  WHERE ......
```

and you should use con.query()  ..not query1

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one update query to toggle the value in is_active field.

**UPDATE tblcompany SET is_active = IF(is_active=1, 0, 1) where cid='" + comid + "';**

And

There is no function as query1 with conn (conn.query1). You have to use the same query function to execute sql query.

**conn.query("sql query", callbackFunction)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
UPDATE tblcompany
    SET is_active = 1 - is_active
    WHERE cid = ?;
```

The `?` is a *parameter placeholder*.  You should learn how to use parameters to pass values into queries.

You can also express this as:

```
UPDATE tblcompany
    SET is_active = NOT is_active
    WHERE cid = ?;
```